# Radio button, remove default value in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, radio-button

I'm trying to figure out of this radio button is checked No or Yes or has not been checked yet..

```
<s:if test="%{! #session['_rbc_session_client_information_complete_prompted_']}">
        <div class="form-inline loba-radio-inline">
            <span><s:text name="applicantInfo.infoComplete.msg"/></span>
            <s:radio id="infoComplete" name="infoComplete" value="" 
            list="#{getText('rbc.no.key'):getText('rbc.no'),
            getText('rbc.yes.key'):getText('rbc.yes')}" />
        </div>
    </s:if>
```

I have a continue button on the same page that calls changeRBC_RIP_G04()

However, i keep getting false, even if nothing is selected,
if i reverse the radio button order, i get true..
I want to know when its unchcked...

```
function changeRBC_RIP_G04() 
{   
    var selectedValue = $('input[name=infoComplete]:checked').val();
    if (selectedValue == 'false') 
    {
        $('#RBC-MSG-011-modal').modal('show');
    }else {

    window.location='rbcDetailPage?newApplication=true'+selectedValue;
    }
};
```

the S tages are from struts 2

Comment: What are those `<s` (s:text, s:radio) tags? I haven't seen them before. Do they belong to a specific framework?

Comment: Maybe because, value="" ??????

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>