# Remove Radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some radio button so in that some Null Value are present so i want to remove it by identify dynamically

```
<input type="radio"  name="Result_radio" id="Result_0"  >Group</input>
<input type="radio"  name="Result_radio" id="Result_1"  >individual</input>
<input type="radio"  name="Result_radio" id="Result_2"  >Null Value</input>
```

Comment: You should search for similar question before you post a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992001/radio-button-remove-default-value-in-js?rq=1
hope that link will help.And you should remove the null value in the server side so that you don't even have to generate the radio button in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input type `radio` don't have closing tags.

Use `label` for the values

```
<input type="radio"  name="Result_radio" id="Result_0" > <label>Group</label>
<input type="radio"  name="Result_radio" id="Result_1" ><label>individual</label>
<input type="radio"  name="Result_radio" id="Result_2" ><label>Null Value</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').each(function() {
    if($(this).next('label').text() == 'Null Value'){
        $(this).next('label').remove();
        $(this).remove();        
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v28QP/1/)**

Comment: Here input is inside label http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/eju3d/.
So you need to use one `.remove` and also you can click on text to check/uncheck radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that your HTML is invalid, and will be interpreted by browsers as:

```
<input type="radio" name="Result_radio" id="Result_0">Group
<input type="radio" name="Result_radio" id="Result_1">individual
<input type="radio" name="Result_radio" id="Result_2">Null Value
```

Therefore, we have to check for the next text node after each input:

```
// For each radio button
$('input:radio').each(function() {

    // If trimmed text after the current radio button is 'Null Value',
    if($.trim(this.nextSibling.nodeValue) == 'Null Value') {

        // Remove the text node
        $(this.nextSibling).remove();

        // Remove current radio button
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vJ8xN/